# Signal-flow graphical summary of back-propagation learning

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to draw signal-flow graphical summary of back-propagation learning.  Top part of the graph: forward pass. Bottom part of the graph: backward pass as shown below:

[image]

Since this is my first time drawing a figure in Tikz, I am a little overwhelmed by the complexity of this figure. Any help will be appreciated. Also, if you can tell me which tool you used to create this for LaTeX, it will help as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me tell you, this is not the best drawing to start using tikz. It has a lot of elements to draw: lines, circles, arrows... That said, I think there are two keys here: positioning the necessary coordinates and using the `\foreach` command.

First I will provide you with a "map" with my defined coordinates, thus I avoid to explain where is each one.
[image]

Now, for the code. It could be less, if I put together more things in the same `\foreach`. But I think that separating the coordinates, the lines, the labels, etc., we gain a bit in readability. Well, so I hope. I also use the `arrows.meta` and `decorations.markings` libraries to put the arrows in the middle of the lines.

It is as follows.

```
\documentclass [border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage    {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\definecolor   {myblue}{HTML}{3CADEF}
\tikzset       {myposition/.store in=\myposition,myposition=0.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [%
    scale=0.8,thick,line cap=round,line join=round,%
    myarrow/.style=%
    {%
      decoration={markings,mark=at position \myposition with {\arrow{Stealth}}},
      postaction={decorate}
    }
  ]
  % Coordinates
  \foreach\j in {1,2,3}
  {%
    \foreach[count=\xi]\i in {0,8}
    {%
      \coordinate (A\xi\j) at (\i+\j,0);
      \coordinate (B\xi\j) at (\i+\j,8-2*\j);
      \coordinate (C\xi\j) at (\i+\j,8);
      \coordinate (D\xi\j) at (\i+\j,16-2*\j);
    }
    \coordinate (E\j) at  (5, 8-2*\j);
    \coordinate (F\j) at  (7, 8-2*\j);
    \coordinate (G\j) at (13, 8-2*\j);
    \coordinate (H\j) at (-3,16-2*\j);
    \coordinate (I\j) at  (0,16-2*\j);
    \coordinate (J\j) at  (5,16-2*\j);
    \coordinate (K\j) at  (8,16-2*\j);
    \coordinate (L\j) at (13,16-2*\j);
    \coordinate (M\j) at (15,16-2*\j);
    \coordinate (N\j) at (17,16-2*\j);
  }
  \coordinate (H0) at (-3,16);
  \coordinate (J0) at ( 5,16);
  % Blue lines
  \foreach\j in {1,2,3}
  {%
    \foreach\i in {1,2}
    {%
      \draw[myblue,myarrow,myposition=0.4] (D\i\j) -- (C\i\j);
      \draw[myblue,myarrow,myposition=0.6] (C\i\j) -- (B\i\j);
      \draw[myblue,myarrow,myposition=0.6] (B\i\j) -- (A\i\j);
    }
    \draw[myblue,myarrow,myposition=0.3]   (G\j)   -- (B2\j);
    \draw[myblue,myarrow,myposition=0.6]   (B2\j)  -- (F\j);
    \draw[myblue]                          (E\j)   -- (B1\j);
    \foreach\k in {1,2,3}
    {%
      \draw[myblue,myarrow,myposition=0.3] (F\j)   -- (E\k);
    }
  }
  % Black lines
  \foreach\j in {1,2,3}
  {%
    \draw[myarrow,myposition=0.8] (I\j)  -- (D1\j);
    \draw[myarrow]                (D1\j) -- (J\j);
    \draw[myarrow               ] (K\j)  -- (D2\j);
    \draw[myarrow,myposition=0.6] (D2\j) -- (L\j);
    \draw[myarrow,myposition=0.6] (L\j)  -- (M\j);
    \draw[myarrow,myposition=0.6] (N\j)  -- (M\j);
    \draw[myarrow,myposition=1]   (M\j)  --++ (0,-0.5);
    \foreach\i in {0,...,3} \foreach\k/\l in {H/I,J/K}
    {%
      \draw[myarrow,myposition=0.3] (\k\i) -- (\l\j);
    }
    
  }
  % Circles
  \def\r{0.1} % radius
  \foreach\j in {1,2,3}
  {%
    \foreach\i in {A1,B1,C1,D1,A2,B2,C2,D2,E,F,G}
    {%
      \draw[myblue,fill=white] (\i\j) circle (\r);
    }
    \foreach\i in {H,...,N}
    {%
      \draw[fill=white] (\i\j) circle (\r);
    }
  }
  \draw[fill=white] (H0) circle (\r);
  \draw[fill=white] (J0) circle (\r);
  % Labels
  \foreach\j in {1,2,3}
  {
    \node         at (N\j)                [above]         {$d_\j$};
    \node         at (M\j)                [yshift=-0.6cm] {$e_\j$};
    \node         at (L\j)                [above right]   {$o_\j-1$};
    \node         at ($(D2\j)!0.6!(L\j)$) [above]         {$\varphi(\cdot)$};
    \node         at (J\j)                [above]         {$y_\j^{(1)}$};
    \node         at ($(D1\j)!0.5!(J\j)$) [above]         {$\varphi(\cdot)$};
    \node         at (H\j)                [left]          {$x_\j$};
    \node[myblue] at (G\j)                [right]         {$e_\j$};
    \foreach\i in {1,2}
    {%
      \node[myblue]                          at (D\i\j)                 [above]        {$v_\j^{(\i)}$};
      \node[myblue,fill=white,inner sep=1pt] at (C\i\j)                 [yshift=0.4cm] {$v_\j^{(\i)}$};
      \node[myblue]                          at ($(B\i\j)!0.4!(C\i\j)$) [right]        {$\varphi(\cdot)$};
      \node[myblue]                          at (A\i\j)                 [below]        {$\delta_\j^{(\i)}$};
    }
    \foreach[count=\xi]\i in {H,J}
    {%
      \node at (\i0)  [above]            {$+1$};
      \node at (\i0)  [xshift=1.2cm]     {$w_{10}^{(\xi)}=b^{(\xi)}$};
      \node at (\i3)  [below,xshift=1cm] {$w_{13}^{(\xi)}$};
    }
  }
  \node[myblue] at ($(E3)!0.5!(F3)$) [below] {$w_{31}^{(2)}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Simply excellent. +1.

Comment: Sir, you are my savior! Excellent work. Thanks for sharing it with the world! :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX! Some ideas how to tame this beast:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  dot/.style={
    circle, draw, inner sep=1.5pt
  },
  arrow/.style={
    decoration={markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow{latex}}},
    postaction={decorate}
  }
]

\node[dot, label={90:$\upsilon_1^{(1)}$}] (u11) at (0,0) {};

\node[dot, label={300:$\varphi^\prime(\cdot)$}] (p1) at (0,-2) {};

\node[dot] (x1) at (2,-2) {};

\node[dot, label={270:$\delta_1^{(1)}$}] (d11) at (0,-5) {};

\draw[arrow] (u11) -- node[pos=.5, label={180:$\varphi^\prime(\cdot)$}] {} (p1);
\draw (p1) -- (x1);
\draw[arrow] (p1) -- (d11);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can always consult the very comprehensive and comprehensible [Ti*k*Z manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for basic help.

Comment: Thank you for giving a head start. :)

Comment: I just discovered that there seems to exist an unofficial package already or such things: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/signal-flow-building-blocks/